# Evaluate variable lazily

Tags: ansible, lazy-evaluation

I have a variable reference to a variable that is not known when the Playbook starts and the reference is evaluated. Is there a way to lazy load the variable when it is actually accessed?

In the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    l01lin08:
      bamboo_agents_it:
        - bamboo_agent_app_name: bamboo-agent-it
          bamboo_agent_install_dir: /data/bamboo-agent-it
          bamboo_agent_capabilities: "{{ bamboo_agent_capabilities_it }}"
        - # ...
        - # ...
      bamboo_agent_capabilities_it:
        # Error: bamboo_agent_install_dir is not known when evaluating the variable
        capabilitiy: '{{ bamboo_agent_install_dir }}/bla/blubb'
        another.one: 123
        is.something: true
```

`bamboo_agent_capabilities_it.capability` references to `bamboo_agents_it[].bamboo_agent_install_dir` which is not known in this context.

The capabilities is a set of key-value-pairs which can be everything. The values are not always paths and the keys are not always the same. Thus I cannot tell when to add a parent path and when not in the target task.

In the playbook I call a role in a loop over `bamboo_agents_it`:

```yaml
  tasks:
    Install all bamboo agents
    - include_role:
        name: bamboo-agent-linux
      vars:
        bamboo_agent_app_name: '{{ item.bamboo_agent_app_name }}'
        bamboo_agent_install_dir: '{{ item.bamboo_agent_install_dir }}'
        bamboo_agent_capabilities: '{{ item.bamboo_agent_capabilities }}'
      loop: '{{ bamboo_agents_it }}'
```

In this loop `item.bamboo_agent_install_dir` is available but I want to have a generic config definition. I don't want to handle these single keys separately.

- Is there a way to solve this problem in a generic way?
- Maybe can I lazyload the variable in the task when it is accessed?

A workaround I'm using is to replace a placeholder insteed. But I hope there is more idiomatic way:

```yaml
# Inventory
      bamboo_agent_capabilities_it:
        # Error: bamboo_agent_install_dir is not known when evaluating the variable
        capabilitiy: '[bamboo_agent_install_dir]/bla/blubb'

# Task:
  lineinfile:
    path: '{{ bamboo_agent_install_dir }}/bin/bamboo-capabilities.properties'
    line: '{{ item.key }}={{ item.value | replace("[bamboo_agent_install_dir]", bamboo_agent_install_dir) }}'
  loop: '{{ bamboo_agent_default_capabilities | dict2items + bamboo_agent_capabilities | dict2items }}'
```

Comment: Well, actually, what you are trying should work. Could you share your Ansible and Jinja version.

Comment: Variables are always lazily evaluated, so you'll need to provide more information about what exactly is failing.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to declare the name that you would expect the variable to be named after:

```yaml
bamboo_agent_capabilities_it:
  capability: /foo/bar
  dir: bamboo_agent_install_dir
```

Then use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) to fetch the value of that variable, for example:

```yaml
bamboo_agent_capabilities: "{{ lookup('vars', item.bamboo_agent_capabilities.dir) }}{{ item.bamboo_agent_capabilities.capability }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    bamboo_agents_it:
      - bamboo_agent_capabilities: "{{ bamboo_agent_capabilities_it }}"
    bamboo_agent_capabilities_it:
      capability: /foo/bar
      dir: bamboo_agent_install_dir

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        bamboo_agent_install_dir: /path/to/dir

    - debug:
        msg: 
          bamboo_agent_capabilities: "{{ lookup('vars', item.bamboo_agent_capabilities.dir) }}{{ item.bamboo_agent_capabilities.capability }}" 
      loop: "{{ bamboo_agents_it }}"
```

This yields:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'bamboo_agent_capabilities': {'capability': '/foo/bar', 'dir': 'bamboo_agent_install_dir'}}) => 
  msg:
    bamboo_agent_capabilities: /path/to/dir/foo/bar

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I clarified the capabilities variable a bit. It contains key-value-pairs of capabilities like variable=value. The values are not always filesystem paths. It may be everything. Thus I cannot tell when there is a path that requires the variable and when not.

Comment: Well, you can since you defined one as `capabilitiy: '{{ bamboo_agent_install_dir }}/bla/blubb'` (so containing a path) and the other one as `another.one: 123`, so not containing a path.